# Use JOIN instead of sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT `badges`.`id`,
       `badges`.`en_seo`

FROM   `badges`

WHERE  `status` IS  NULL
AND    `id`     NOT IN
       (SELECT `badges_id`

        FROM   `users_badges`

        WHERE  `users_id` = 1)
```

Can I rewrite this code using JOINS?

Comment: Added the mysql tag. The only platform that uses backtics ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact equivalent to your query is:

```
SELECT    `badges`.`id`,
          `badges`.`en_seo`
FROM      `badges`
LEFT JOIN `users_badges`
       ON `badges`.`id` = `users_badges`.`badges_id`
      AND `users_badges`.`users_id` = 1
WHERE     `badges`.`status` IS NULL
  AND     `users_badges`.`users_id` IS NULL
```

However, it's a common practice to use aliases like in Juan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use alias for your table names

```
SELECT b.`id`,
       b.`en_seo`
FROM   `badges` b
LEFT JOIN `users_badges` ub
  ON b.`id`= ub.`badges_id`
 and ub.`users_id` = 1
WHERE b.`status` IS  NULL
 AND ub.`id` IS NULL
```

Comment: I guess, you should replace `ub.id` with `ub.badges_id`